# Using Mac OS X (Xcode 4.1) for FreeBSD development

Tags: xcode, macos, cross-platform, cross-compiling, freebsd

Hi stackoverflow community!

I am about to start developing patches for FreeBSD Ports Collection (pkgng utility) using C programming language.

The problem is that I am using Mac OS X and I am really do not want to switch to another operating system. I have installed Freebsd 9.0 on Parallels Desktop VM. Xcode 4.1 seems to be rather nice development tool for C.

Is it possible to implement development for FreeBSD via Xcode 4.1? How to set up project environment for such form of development and compile source for FreeBSD?

I am also opened for any other suggestions concerning cross-platform development using MacOS X to develop patches for FreeBSD. Which is the best way to organize all necessary stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to develop patches for pkgng, I would strongly suggest that you compile and test the code on FreeBSD, because it is the only system that uses the ports and packages system that pkgng interfaces with. So unless it can cross-compile for FreeBSD, using any OS X IDE is probably not a good idea.

I'm not familiar with Parallels, but there is probably a file-sharing mechanism that you can set up between OS X and the FreeBSD running in the VM. That way you can edit your files on OS X and use them under FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

X Code is really nice, and I would lean toward using it but then doing regular builds on a system actually running FreeBSD.  If you have source for everything you're using (except standard libraries whose interfaces match), there is no reason not to work on OS X with Xcode.  You can build your own libraries if need be.  One thing writing cross platform does (provided you regularly build on the other platform) is make your code more portable.  It's easier to avoid using platform specific "extensions".